# Mount point user, group and permissions changed after mounting hard drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mount

I am mounting a hard drive to my Ubuntu box under `/media/newhdd`, which *before* mounting has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root team 4096 Jan 19 17:26 newhdd
drwxr-x---+ 2 root root 4096 May 14  2020 oem
```

I had already changed the group to the `team` group. *After* mounting, however, what I see is:

```
drwx------  4 29999 29999 4096 Jan 19 19:48 newhdd
drwxr-x---+ 2 root  root  4096 May 14  2020 oem
```

What do those numbers mean? And why have the permissions changed?

Info: I'm mounting with `sudo mount /dev/sda /media/newhdd`.

Comment: Did you mount it on another computer than you set these UID/GID?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks, I received the HDD from the supplier with the machine, my guess is they mounted then formatted it on another Ubuntu box. Actually the upper limit for dynamic UIDs on my machine is 59999, not 29999. I have actually changed the ownership and permissions now, so it doesn't seem to have been anything particularly significant. Just curious what it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, permissions aren't changed. Your local UID/GID allocation doesn't match that of the system where permissions were set, and just your system displays them differently. But permissions on disk still are correct, if you were moved the storage to the system where these were set, it'll display them as intended.

---

Each system has its own set of IDs. In general they are allocated as needed, when needed. For example, when you create a group, a system allocates a GID for it and stores allocation into `/etc/group` (by default). Similarly, when you create a user, system allocates an UID for it and stores allocation into `/etc/passwd`.

System accounts aren't much different. There is a differences between distros; for example, some distro may "statically allocate" some UIDs and GIDs for certain applications; those allocations don't get stored when the system is installed, but when you install a software which needs its own account, installer creates accounts for them with predefined UID/GID. Other distros (Gentoo) don't do even that; UIDs and GIDs are allocated anew on first software installation, if needed.

There are some settings which define pools, from which these UIDs and GIDs are taken to be allocated. Those lines in `/etc/adduser.conf` is one of them, but there are others; for example, my system doesn't have /etc/adduser.conf, but I have `/etc/default/useradd`. You may override that on account creation by supplying a concrete IDs , like this: `useradd -u 1100 -G users newuser` will create user with UID 1100, regardless of any configured ranges.

So, what names correspond to what UIDs/GIDs almost always differ from one system to another. It depends strongly on the history of the system: which distro it is; software is installed and in which order; which users are created and in which order and so on. The only truth we can say about "any" Linux system is that the user `root` always has UID `0`, and the group `root` always has GID `0`.

For example, if I install two identical Ubuntu's and then create on one user "alice" first, it can have UID 1000, then "bob", which probably have UID 1001; on another system I create "bob` first which will get 1000 and "alice" second, she receives 1001.

On the other hand, file systems don't store user and group names; they store numbers, UIDs and GIDs. Expanding prior example, if I create a file on first system and make its owner "alice", her UID 1000 will be written into file system metadata. If I move a storage media to the second machine and access that file, "bob" will appear as it's owner, because file has UID 1000 in the metadata, and  on the second machine that UID corresponds to "bob".

What if there is no UID allocated? Don't worry, OS itself doesn't bother with names, it only uses IDs, and names are only translated only by userspace. Userspace tools usually just show "digital" IDs when there is no allocation for them in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`.

Windows systems aren't much different. It has a single "numbering domain" of IDs, called RIDs, both user and group security identifiers are taken from it (Linux counts UIDs and GIDs separately). First local user often has RID of 500. RIDs combined with "numbering domain" give SIDs, which are written into file system metadata. Allocations are stored in the SAM database.

---

This leads to very important problem: how to centrally manage a set of computers, for storage to be transferrible and so on? There are several solutions for that. One, by far most used, is to have a central system which manages allocations, and all joined systems query allocations from it. On local systems, those allocated IDs often mapped to some "ID domain". For example, MS Active Directory always has a Domain Controller with active FSMO role `RID master`; this is exactly a system which manages allocations in the domain. (If you think of it more, you'll get *why* this role was made FSMO, a "single master operation" role.) So permissions of domain-owned files will render correctly on all systems in the domain, even if media moves between computers. But if media is moved outside of the domain, all described effects of broken mapping will arise. Linux system can use central allocation too, there is NIS, or even MS AD controller can allocate UIDs/GIDs for Linux systems joined into a AD domain.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks! I'm going to take a few days to absorb all that, incredibly useful info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a dynamically generated UID, and it's choosing the upper limit for such ids from `/etc/adduser.conf`:

```
# FIRST_[GU]ID to LAST_[GU]ID inclusive is the range of UIDs of dynamically
# allocated user accounts/groups.
FIRST_UID=1000
LAST_UID=29999
```